# Conda config shows extra item than configured

Tags: ubuntu, conda

`conda config --show-sources` shows there is only one configuration file, which is `/home/gqqnbig/.condarc`. This file sets `envs_dirs` to 2 locations.

```
$ conda config --show-sources --debug
DEBUG conda.gateways.logging:set_verbosity(231): verbosity set to 2
==> /home/gqqnbig/.condarc <==
envs_dirs:
  - ~/shared/.conda/envs
  - /opt/anaconda3/envs
pkgs_dirs:
  - /opt/anaconda3/pkgs
  - ~/shared/.conda/pkgs

==> cmd_line <==
debug: True
```

Nevertheless, `conda config --show` says the calculated value for `envs_dirs` has 3 locations.

```
$ conda config --show envs_dirs --debug
DEBUG conda.gateways.logging:set_verbosity(231): verbosity set to 2
DEBUG conda.base.context:root_writable(498): [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/anaconda3/conda-meta/history'
envs_dirs:
  - /home/gqqnbig/shared/.conda/envs
  - /opt/anaconda3/envs
  - /home/gqqnbig/.conda/envs
```

How does the third location get populated? How do I prevent conda from using `/home/gqqnbig/.conda/envs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Conda Default Environment Directories

Both the `$CONDA_ROOT_PREFIX/envs` and the `~/.conda/envs` directories are [baked into the Conda code](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/86b4aea54b27666e33b835063c8e37f7dfb35264/conda/base/context.py#L76) and will always be *appended* to the list in the `.condarc` (what your first command shows) to generate the final calculated `context.envs_dirs` (what your second command shows). Conda will only ever resort to using it if all the higher precedent locations are unwriteable.

I don't know the history of this part of the code, but I suspect this default folder is mostly there as a fallback for users on shared systems where the Conda instance (and thus `$CONDA_ROOT_PREFIX/envs`) is in an unwriteable location. That is, baking-in these two directories tries to ensure the existence of at least one writeable environment folder in both the single-user and shared-user install scenarios.

#### Force Read-Only

I'm not totally sure, but it doesn't look like Conda relies on this folder for any other purposes. So, if one really wanted to ensure that Conda never uses it, you could simply make the directory read only:

```bash
chmod -w ~/.conda/envs
```

To be safe, you could try setting it, then test creating an environment with the verbosity turned up to check for issues.