# Conda environments being created in home directory rather than in /opt/miniconda3 by default

Tags: conda

When I tried creating a conda environment

```
conda create -n py2-env python=2.7
```

py2-env is created in $HOME/.conda/envs/py2-env

rather than /opt/miniconda3/envs where they should go by default. I have the same .condarc file as other users on the server, all of whose environments go by default to /opt

I can get around the problem temporarily by using

```
conda create -p /opt/miniconda/envs/py2-env
```

However, I would like my environments to be created there by default. What do I need to (re)set in order to do so?

Comment: What does `conda config --show envs_dirs` output? Does `conda info` show this as a writable directory by your user?

Comment: It shows both my home directory and the /opt/miniconda3/envs directory, so both are writable. As I mentioned in the original post, I can create environments in /opt if I sue the conda create -p. I wish to change the settings so the default conda create -p creates environments there rather than in my home directory, but I can't find a way to do this.

Comment: Can you change the order? Does running `conda config --add envs_dirs /opt/miniconda/envs` change the priority?

Comment: The strange thing is that the /opt directory is shown first under --show env_dirs, which should mean that it's given priority, but it doesn't. Resetting the config as you suggest doesn't change anything, unfortunately.

Comment: Might be able to force things by making the user-specific one read-only. e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/66443636/570918

Comment: Are there anything in the user profile that is overriding the default location of which conda saves a created environment?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `CONDA_ROOT_PREFIX` environment variable to `/opt/miniconda/`